# Sorting strings in C++ using operator <

Tags: c++, string, sorting, stl, operators

The following array is given in C++ code:

```
char strings[105][105];
```

What is the correct way to write `operator<` to sort the strings using `STL` `sort` function and is it possible at all?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework problem.

Comment: why would you use an stl sort with character arrays?  not use std::strings?

Comment: What strings. I don't see any strings (just a big (2-D)array of characters).

Comment: std::string has performance implications and it is not a homework problem.

Comment: @Martin: let the string for purpose of this problem be defined as an array of characters.

Comment: @Leonid: Did you profile and *prove* that `std::string` was too slow for your use?

Comment: @DeadMG: No and I'm not going to do that as it is **not** part of the question.

Comment: To use std::sort you need to write your own specialized iterators that use arrays as there members and provide some niffty copying solution. As has been said several times now std::string is going to way easier to write and maintain and probably much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overload `operator<` for pointers, but you don't need to, since std::sort can accept any comparison function (or functor).

Another problem is that the sort algorithm cannot swap arrays, because they are not assignable. But you can sort an array of pointers into the two-dimensional array (leaving the original array as it is).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

bool compare_cstring(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
}

int main()
{
    const int count = 5;
    char strings[count][10] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
    char* sorted_view[count];
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        sorted_view[i] = strings[i];
    }

    std::sort(sorted_view, sorted_view + count, compare_cstring);
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        puts(sorted_view[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That code actually looks suspiciously like C code, not C++ which would use `std::string`.

There's no way to write an `operator<` that will work with `std::sort` because there's no swap that will work right unless you write that TOO.

Using `std::string` would make this pretty trivial, otherwise you'll have to write your own `operator<` (look at the C function `strcmp`) and `swap`  functions.

EDIT: Note that swapping `std::string`s will almost certainly be faster than swapping huge swaths of memory in a `char` array.

Comment: The goal is to use `sort` function from STL which is not available in C. That might not be possible because of the way iterators work. `std::string` provides unnecessary overhead that I would like to avoid. Wrapping character array in a `struct` provides a way to use `sort` function overloading `operator<` for that struct. Wondering if there are more ways to sort character arrays using `sort`.

Comment: @Leonid Did you profile and show that `std::string` is as slow as you think it is and is an actual bottleneck in your application? Simpler programs (for example making use of abstractions like `string`) strangely enough tend to perform BETTER because you're able to concentrate on high-level algorithms rather than low-level details.

Comment: In my case `std::string` would have to do dynamic memory allocation which I'd like to avoid by using static character arrays. I'm not curious at all to find which is faster at all for the purpose of **this question**. I'm curious to find whether it is possible to use `sort` on a character array.

Comment: @Leonid: dynamic memory allocation allows to simply swap the internal pointers to the strings instead of copying back and forth all those characters. And keep in mind that `std::string` usually do not use dynamic allocation for short strings (where the cost of dynamic allocation outweights its benefits).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to write an `operator<` to work with `char` arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you really **do** need to sort a 2D array row-wise, it's a bit difficult to make `std::sort()` do this for you, even given a working comparer functor: it would need some sort of iterator adapter.

However, you can easily use other in-place sorting algorithms, such as selection sort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template<int N>
bool char_array_less(const char(&l)[N], const char(&r)[N])
{
   return std::char_traits<char>::compare(&l[0], &r[0], N) < 0;
// for a more general solution
// return std::lexicographical_compare(&l[0], &l[0]+N, &r[0], &r[0]+N);
}

template<int N>
void swap_char_arrays( char(*l)[N], char(*r)[N])
{
    std::swap_ranges(&(*l)[0], &(*l)[0]+N, &(*r)[0]);
}

const int ROWS = 105;
const int COLS = 105;
int main()
{
    char a[ROWS][COLS] = {"foo", "bar", "whatever" };

    for(char(*i)[COLS] = a; i != a+ROWS; ++i)
        swap_char_arrays(i,
                         std::min_element(i, a+ROWS, char_array_less<COLS>));

    for(int i=0; i<ROWS; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/15hRB